# Should “Hell” be capitalized?

Tags: capitalization, proper-nouns

I am of the belief that Hell should be capitalized because real or not, it is the name of a place, and thus a proper noun. It should be capitalized correct?

I have seen it written without capitalization plenty of times, but I suspect that most of those were just due to laziness or illiteracy (it tends to be written with a lower-case ‘h’ mostly on the Internet–sigh).

Other uses, including expletives seem to use it as a place name as well:

> - *What [in] the Hell‽*
> - *Go to Hell!*

Google gives mixed results and checking the WikiPedia entry for [Hell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hell) to get a proper definition does indicate that it is a location, but even on that same page, there are plenty of instances with a lower-case ‘h’.

Is there a situation in which it would not be capitalized? What about uses as an adjective:

> *that job was Hell*?

Comment: That's a hella cool question!

Comment: @Mehrdad, knock it off Cartman.

Comment: For the record, I have since capitalized it only when referring to the location.

Comment: I agree with the answer of @user2683, not the selected answer because "hell" needn't be capitalized when it is used as a proper noun.  It certainly isn't in the Bible.  There just are certain words that fall into the gray area between being a proper noun and being a common noun for a thing there's only one of, thus making it so you can pretty much do whatever the *hell* you want for those words (e.g., "the Earth" and "the earth," "the Internet" and "the internet," "the Devil" and "the devil," etc.). I've sometimes wondered why "the sky" and "the universe" don't fall into this quagmire.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

"Hell" is capitalized when it is used as a proper noun. That is, you capitalize it when you are referring to it as a specific place. However, it can be perfectly legitimate to leave it uncapitalized if you are not referring to a specific place.

"That job was hell" does not refer to a specific location, but rather a nebulous concept of torture. Thus, it is not capitalized in this sentence.

Comment: I agree.  (well unless the job literally was Hell, although I would say in that case you have bigger problems than grammar)

Comment: of the Corn, sounds good to me. @advs89, true, but in this economy, a job is a job. `:-D`

Comment: CMoS says only to capitalize if used in a religious context. (CMoS 8.108)

Answer (score 16):

*Hell* need not be capitalized, even when it refers to a specific place, in the same way we need not capitalize *equator* (see for example Larry Trask's [*Guide to Punctuation*](http://www.informatics.sussex.ac.uk/department/docs/punctuation/node27.html#SECTION00081000000000000000)).

The *[Cambridge Advanced Learner's Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/hell_1)* also allows for it to remain uncapitalized. Its capitalization then is possibly due to its religious significance and not its reference to a specific place.

Checking several bibles (that is as real as hell can be) also shows that it need not be capitalized.

Comment: But why? It is a place and every student learns that place names are capitalized.

Comment: From WikiPedia: *A proper noun or proper name is a noun representing a unique entity, as distinguished from a common noun, which describes a class of entities.* Unless “Toilet” is a specific city, then it isn’t analogous.

Comment: Toilet is not a proper name of a place, whereas Hell is.

Comment: Hell is the name of a particular instance of a fiery torturous venue.  If, for instance, you named your toilet "T-man," then it would be referring to your specific toilet (a specific instance of a toilet).  In that case, "T-man" would be capitalized.

Comment: @Jasper Loy:  In Physics, a _pole_ is a well-defined and common noun.  When someone says "the south pole," they are saying _the pole that is to the south_.  It's an adjective modifying a common noun.  If the south pole were called "Harry," then it _would_ have to be capitalized.  Toilet is also a common noun.  Hell can be either.  In most of the examples provided by the question, Hell is a proper noun.

Comment: Take a look at [definition three](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/equator) for _equator_.  "a circle separating a surface into two congruent parts."  If it's using that definition, it's not capitalized.  If referring to _our_ equator on Earth, then it is.

Comment: All of this is sometimes relaxed, though, for words that are common.  (which is probably your point)  That doesn't necessarily make it "correct" though.  (whatever "correct" means)

Comment: (I wrote that last comment before I saw your most recent one)

Comment: I just now read the [excerpt in question](http://www.informatics.sussex.ac.uk/department/docs/punctuation/node27.html)... I'll admit I'm not a linguist but I don't see how _the equator_ isn't "strictly a proper name."  It fits the dictionary definition of "proper name/noun" perfectly.  Even longer articles on the subject describe it that way.

Comment: @Jasper:  Yes he does.  He also says that it's not wrong, though.  And as I mentioned before, the dictionary definition describes a "proper noun" in a way that fits _equator_ perfectly.  (Dictionaries have entire teams of linguists behind them)

Comment: @Jasper:  Same here.  It definitely looks like it's worth a read.

Comment: The equator isn’t really a *specific* place, but rather a general area because it encompasses a wide range of location. Then again the Prime Meridian or International Date Line are similar (albeit smaller and more specific)…

Comment: @Jasper Loy, but then so is My House. `:-)`

Comment: +1. This answer is correct. Peter Of The Corn's answer is wrong. [A quick Google search](http://www.google.com/search?q=hell+site%3Avatican.va) shows that the Vatican usually does not capitalize *hell*, even when it is apparently being used as a proper noun.

Comment: @advs89: I would regard "equator" as being like "moon".  The moons of mars are called "Phobos" and "Deimos", while the moon of Earth is called "the Moon".  Mars, like Earth, has an equator, but unlike Earth's (which is called "the Equator"), the equator of Mars has no special name.

Comment: @Synetech: Every planet or moon which rotates around a celestial north/south axis will have an equator (lowercase).  The Equator (uppercase) is the equator of the Earth.

Comment: @supercat, yes, and many gardens on Earth are filled with earth every spring, but nobody borrows a cup of hell or drives a hell or has a hell-sandwich.

Comment: @Synetech: Hot sauce vendors might disagree with some of your last statements.  `>:*3`

Answer (score -6):

If you believe it's a real place, then make it capitalized.

Hypothetical locations, on the other hand, can go without capitalization - no one would capitalize "la-la land", for example.

Comment: I suppose in the context of an RPG where there could be multiple hells, then sure, but in the Biblical context, there is a single Hell, regardless of existence, thus making it a proper noun. As for la-la-land, if it is used as a synonym for Los Angeles, then I believe it is indeed capitalized.

Comment: *Belief* has nothing to do with whether you capitalize it or not. Proper nouns are capitalized. You wouldn't write "atlantis" simply because you do not believe it exists.

Comment: If _la-la land_ refers to a specific hypothetical place, then it **should** be capitalized.  Also, as a rebuttal to your assertion that hypothetical locations don't have to be capitalized, consider works of fiction.  Would you argue that you could get away with not capitalizing Narnia even though it doesn't exist?  (granted, that's fictional and not _hypothetical_ but the difference in the two grammatically is arguably negligible)

Comment: @Robert Cartaino:  I agree.  Atlantis is a good example (since it is technically "hypothetical" and not just fictional).  To expand my original argument, I would say that because you always capitalize specific fictional places and because you always capitalize specific real places and because _hypothetical_ tells us that it is either real or fictional, then hypothetical places, too, should be capitalized.

Comment: Also, I would argue that "la-la land" is a _fictional_ location and not a hypothetical one.  It's only hypothetical if there exists people who hypothesize that it exists (people who don't currently reside in an insane asylum).  And since it's fictional and a proper noun, it _must_ be capitalized (just like Narnia, etc.)

Comment: @Synetech inc. , what is RPG?

Comment: @vgv8, role-playing-game like *Dungeons & Dragons* or *World of Warcraft*. Fantasy things like those tend to have multiple planes, dimensions, worlds, heavens, hells, etc.

Comment: @Synetech inc., take care because most people understand RPG as ["Rocket-Propelled Grenade"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rocket-propelled_grenade) originating its abbreviation from similar abbreviation of Soviet РПГ(RPG) - [Ручной Противотанковый Гранатомёт](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%91%D1%82)

Comment: @vgv8, @Synetech Inc.: Both meanings are fairly common in English (though neither is universally understood, even by native speakers).

Comment: Capitalization rules are independent of any belief.

Comment: `Take care because most people understand RPG as "Rocket-Propelled Grenade"` @Genady, yes, but context + common-sense/Google = no confusion.