# Greek mythology: the underworld vs the Underworld

Tags: meaning-in-context, differences, capitalization

I have just read the myth of Orpheus [here](http://www.greeka.com/greece-myths/orpheus-eurydice.htm). The writer used *the underworld* and *the Underworld* alternatively - not to mention *the upper world* and *the Upper World* - which made me wonder which would be more appropriate to use.

I am editing some texts concerning the myth - the reason I should be consistent - and so wanted to hear from you.

Comment: It looks like the writer has simply been lazy.

Comment: I think it's an inconsistency issue. But like I said in the comment below the first answer to this question, the Underworld is a specific place. Like Mecca or The Holy Land or Hell (which is written as a proper noun in Christian theology). One might talk about the physics of the universe, but then use it as a proper noun when philosophizing, speaking about Universal love. Collective Consciousness. The difference between he, the mortal, and He, the God.

Answer (score 1):

Since it **IS** a name of a place, it is a proper noun, and therefore should be capitalized.

Comment: How do you explain the use of the definite article (“the”), then? Why do you say that “the underworld” is a proper noun when “the basement” and “the world” are not?

Comment: @Scott - Because the Underworld is a specific place. Like Mecca or The Holy Land or Hell (which is written as a proper noun in Christian theology).

Comment: I can’t recall hearing anybody referring to “the Mecca” or “the Hell”. Maybe “the hell”, using it as a generic word (e.g., “We all end in the hell of our own choosing.”) or as an exclamation (“what the hell?”).

Comment: @Scott There are plenty of names and proper nouns which are used with definite articles (The Bronx, The Bahamas, the United States, the Ukraine, the Appalachians, the Wild West, the North Pole, etc.). The presence of a definite article says little to nothing about whether something is a proper noun or not. I would disagree that _the U/underworld_ is necessarily the name of a place—it’s a **descriptor** of a place, not its actual name (that would be _Hades_ or one of the many other names it has)—but that doesn’t mean it shouldn’t be capitalised either (_the Holy Land_ is also a descriptor).

Answer (score 0):

I think that this should not be capitalized. If the proper name was “Underworld” (like Hell, or Hades, or Land of the Dead) it would be capitalized, but then you wouldn’t need “the.” So “the underworld” is more of a generic or non-specific term than a proper place name.

Comment: [Some proper nouns take "the"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/59271/why-there-is-the-before-some-names-but-not-others): e.g. "the United States", "the White House".

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, either would be fine.

The Google Ngram Viewer shows the following frequencies for "the underworld" and "the Underworld":

[image]

Lowercase is more common overall. Now, that's not taking context into account. I would imagine that "the underworld" would be very strongly preferred in contexts like "the underworld of crime" or "the underworld of the city", but it may be less strongly preferred in other contexts.

Another Ngram Viewer chart that seems relevant:

[image]

This should exclude examples where "the underworld of..." is used. It still looks like lowercase ("the underworld") is more common in this context, so I'd say that is an acceptable choice. But I would say that the uppercase variant "the Underworld", although apparently less common, seems frequent enough to also be an acceptable choice.

---

Related: [Shouldn’t “Heaven” and “Hell” be capitalized, as they are the names of places?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/17650/shouldn-t-heaven-and-hell-be-capitalized-as-they-are-the-names-of-places) and [Should “Hell” be capitalized?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14572/should-hell-be-capitalized); also more distantly [What is the correct capitalization of the words earth and moon?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/152683/what-is-the-correct-capitalization-of-the-words-earth-and-moon) and [Capitalization of the word universe](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/200375/capitalization-of-the-word-universe)